# Copy Azure Storage Data to Development storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-account

I have been working on Asp.Net application which populates UI from azure storage account.

It makes development extremely tedious when for small change in UI code in I need to wait for all data to reload from azure storage (which is extremely slow, unless partionkey & rowkey are provided properly)

> I wish to synchrozise all data in cloud storage account to local dev
>   storage.
>
> I am sure I am not the first one to face this problem. How does
>   community handles this scenario? Is there any tool, which could copy
>   all data including blob & table to local development account?

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to do so, please take a look at Cerebrata Azure Management Cmdlets. It has a Cmdlet for Backing up storage account data using which you can download data from your cloud storage account to your local computer. It also has a Cmdlet for Restoring storage account data using which you can upload this downloaded data into your storage emulator. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I started doing this using C#, but stuck up! With Azure StorageClient 4.3 I couldn't connect to StorageEmulator 3.0. I get BadRequest error.

Comment: I saw your other question and saw that you're running into some issues there. Can you update that question with the error you're getting?

Comment: @GauravMantri, Done:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983482/how-to-copy-azure-containers-blobs