# Organize assets created by Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

We are using AMS for indexing and encoding video blobs. AMS is creating as top level containers to store the assets in the Storage account.

We also have other top level containers such as images, videos, pdfs etc to store blobs which get stored as `\images\<filename>`, `\videos\<filename>`

Storage account is now cluttered with assets from AMS. Is there a way to set a container name to AMS so the assets get generated inside the provided container instead of root level (by pre-appending the container name to the assetfile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have no control over container names for Assets. They have to be unique, that's why there is also GUID associated with the container name.

By the way I wouldn't share a storage account with media services. Media Services should have its own (if not more than one) storage account.

Comment: Can we associate AMS with multiple storage accounts and then move the assets generated in primary account(where all other blobs are stored) to other new storage account. Will AMS retrieve the files automatically from other storage account,

Answer (score 2):

As astaykov mentioned Azure Media Services not providing api to select custom naming scheme for asset storage containers.

Best option will be to use dedicated storage account to storing your own metadata and not reuse account provisioned as part of media services accoount provisioning.

You can also have ability to provide storage account name as part of asset create see parameter StorageAccountName (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974277.aspx#create_an_asset).

When you creating asset with none default storage account name you need to make sure that this storage account associated with media services. This can be done through azure powershell cmdlets or through azure management apis (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt735161.aspx).

If for some reasons you must use only one shared storage account you can simulate folder structure like it described in [Organising Azure Media assets in Blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540457/organising-azure-media-assets-in-blob-storage/16847581)

Comment: Can we associate AMS with multiple storage accounts and then move the assets generated in primary account(where all other blobs are stored) to other new storage account. Will AMS retrieve the files automatically from other storage account,

Comment: Once asset created and associated to account there is no way to update this association.You can copy blobs from old asset to newly created empty asset, but it will be technically two different assets.Later you can delete old asset. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983482/how-to-copy-azure-containers-blobs for example how to move blobs without re-uploading them.